# JasperReports - Passing an Array of Strings from Filter to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

I'm trying to use an multi value column as a filter and passing an array of string but I'm getting this error message:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "ae" does not exist Position: 122
```

Here is part of my `JRXML` file:

```
<parameter name="status" class="java.util.Collection">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {}))]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="status_query" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{status}.isEmpty()
? "null"
: "array" + $P{status}]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[select * from _reports.my_proc($P!{status})]]>
</queryString>
```

Someone has an idea how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it will probably do toString() on your array list, is this what you expect in your procedure?

Comment: I'm expecting a list `['ae']` and not an `["ae"]` with double quotes.

Comment: Since you are passing it as parameter why not pass a String as you expect it?, convert the array list in java to a string according to your format.